# Watir/Ruby selecting next value

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, watir

I am working with a table that has links in the first column:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)

html.css('tr td a').each do |links|
  browser.link(:text=>"#{a}").click
  puts "#{a}"
end
```

How do i display the NEXT value for the link?
If the link name is abcd but the next one is efgh, how do i get it to write the efgh?

Comment: yes sorry ! that's definitely what i meant

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example - eg HTML, inputs and expected output? It is hard to envision exactly what you are trying to achieve. It just seems odd that you are trying to iterate through the links, but wanting to interact with the next link instead. It just sounds like you could iterate through all links skipping the first.

Comment: If there are 3 links lets say directing you to Google, Yahoo, Bing
I want to click on Google and have an output like a puts of Yahoo

Comment: +1 for the sample HTML please, that makes it a lot easier for us to understand your ask, which so far seems to be confusing almost everyone reading this question

Comment: Your ruby code also makes little sense above.  You are iterating over a collection presumably created by nokogiri, you are passing the selected collection item into the loop as "links" but you then never make use of it.  The code inside the loop, is using a variable a, that will not change (while iterating the collection), so that loop code will do the same thing each time through the loop.  Further without knowing the value for a, or having any HTML, I can't tell you what the code inside the loop will do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using the index in the array you are working with.

```
thing = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

(0..thing.length - 1).each do |index| 
  puts thing[index + 1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the use case here (not at all), but this contrived example might point you in the direction that you're looking to go.

Use the `links` method to create an array of `link` objects.  Then, you can print the `text` for the element at the second position but click the element at the first position.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto('http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved')

nav_links = b.div(:class => "navigation").links   

puts nav_links[1].text   #=> NUMBERS
nav_links[0].click
puts b.url               #=> http://www.iana.org/domains
```

The `Enumerable::each_with_index` method might also be useful since it cycles through each element of an array and additionally returns the respective element position.  For example:

```
b.div(:class => "navigation").links.each_with_index { |el, i| puts el.text, i }

#=> DOMAINS
#=> 0
#=> NUMBERS
#=> 1
#=> PROTOCOLS
#=> 2
...
```